# UTF-8 to XML Python cleanup function woes

Tags: python, xml

with code from different sources found here I put together a cleanup function to remove illegal characters from strings to include in an XML file. Some of it is redundant is it is quite messy. None of the functions I found have worked by themselves. I still get some problems trying to import the resulting XML file and punctuation has been removed. Everything is specified as UTF-8. I am not familiar with encodings, so a more elegant function that works would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
def doclean(s):
ranges=[(0, 8),(0xb,0x1f),(0x7f,0x84),(0x86,0x9f),(0xd800,0xdfff),(0xfdd0,0xfddf),(0xfffe,0xffff)]
bad=dict.fromkeys(r for start, end in ranges for r in range(start,end+1))
s=s.translate(bad)
s=re.sub(u"[^\x01-\x7f]+",'',s)
s=re.sub(u'[\x00-\x08\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F%s]','',s)
s=s.replace('\x0b','')
# Take anything out that isn't UTF-8:
s=s.decode('utf-8','ignore').encode('utf-8','ignore')
return s
```

Comment: Could you give your definition of what "illegal characters" are?

Comment: Anything that causes errors in an XML file. Viewing the XML file I create I see parts of the file moved around and dedoubled, very weird... Some characters wreak havock on my file...

Comment: There are no illegal characters for XML. Data provided into XML needs to be encoded. Your approach is somehow "hacky". As long as you don't have an extremely precise knowledge of what you really need to do technically here you'll run into troubles one way or the other. I know what I'm talking about: I learned it the hard way.

Comment: XML supports UTF-8, in fact, it's the standard encoding. So if you encode your data correctly there's no need to remove _any_ characters.

Comment: You should seriously consider migrating to Python 3, where Unicode handling is a lot saner (besides, Python 2 reaches its official End of Life in 2020). In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Python 2.7 is what I have to work with now. I can't be sure the source data respects utf-8, tought it is the declared format...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't perform any filtering. I'd use encoding. That's easier and less error prone. Here is a fragment:

```
def encodeForXML(inputData):
    assert isinstance(inputData, str)
    outputData = ""
    for c in inputData:
        if c == '<':
            outputData += "&lt;"
        elif c == '&':
            outputDdata += "&amp;"
        else:
            outputData += c
    return outputData
```

Then you can wrap it into "XML":

```
return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><myRootNode>" + encodeForXML("foo") + "</myRootNode>"
```

If I remember correctly that should very much do it: The resulting text should be valid XML all the time.

*Additional remark: Of course this example is addressing Python 3. Python 2 is quite outdated.*